# How to install numpy, PIL on Nao robot gentoo linux

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, installation, nao-robot

I have some .py files which include some packages like numpy and PIL. I want to install .py files and  numpy,PIl packages into Nao robot's hardware for my project. (python 2.7, Nao 1.14.5 Gentoo lınux) How Could I do that with putty or anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

On NAOs running NAOqi 2.1, numpy and PIL are already installed by default. Have you checked whether they are installed on your robot?

If not, it could be worth upgrading to NAOqi 2.1 if your hardware supports it.

Comment: is it free to upgrade? And also what about PIL ? How to send .py files into Nao

Comment: You can check the documentation: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/embedded/upgrade.html